# How to add file to existing stash in git?

Tags: git, git-stash

When I did `git stash push <path/to/file>` it created `stash@{0}` for it.
Reusing the same command with different file creates another stash -> `stash@{1}`.
I have other files that logically belong to stash@{0}.

Can I somehow push file to existing stash?

Comment: While creating the stash you could have done,                                                                           
`git stash push <path/to/file1> <path/to/file2>`, push takes multiple files

Comment: A Git stash is just a little clump of commits that aren't on *any* branch. As with any commit, you cannot change anything about it once it's made. All you can do is make a new, different commit—or in this case, a new, different stash—that has the content you want, and stop using the old one. I generally recommend *avoiding* `git stash`: just make normal commits instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you mean akin to `git commit --amend`, I am afraid you are out of luck, but would it be acceptable for your use case, to:

`git stash pop`

and then

`git stash push ORIGINAL_FILES MORE_FILES`

to have the files grouped?

Comment: By default pop command will pop 0th stash i.e. stash@{0} so to pop first nth stash 
git stash pop stash@{n}

and then
git stash push -m "useful message" <path-spec-including-old-and-new-files>

Answer (score 2):

As per git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-ltstashgt),

> `<stash>`
>
> This option is only valid for apply, branch, drop, pop, show
>   commands.
>
> A reference of the form `stash@{<revision>}`. When no `<stash>` is given,
>   the latest stash is assumed (that is, `stash@{0}`).

So you can't do this directly using `push` command of `git stash`.

Probably use this `git stash push <path/to/file1> <path/to/file2> ...` next time as `push` accepts multiple pathspecs (filenames)